# Finding the top numbers in a numeric loop

Tags: javascript

I am scripting a survey and I am trying to figure out a way of looping through a numeric list to find the highest 3 numbers entered using javascript.

Numeric question list
**Q1**

Codes
**1
2
3
4
5**

I want it to loop through all 5 codes find the numeric number in each (can be from 0-10) and compare against all ten codes to pick the highest 3 numbers. Should there be more than three top numbers, then it needs to pick 3 or more.

Example:
Q1

Code 1 - f('Q1')['**1**'] == ('3')

Code 2 - f('Q1')['**2**'] == ('2')

Code 3 - f('Q1')['**3**'] == ('5')

Code 4 - f('Q1')['**4**'] == ('0')

Code 5 - f('Q1')['**5**'] == ('5')

In this example the script I need would pick out code 1 (3), code 3 (5) and code 5 (5) being the highest 3 numbers.

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Do give us an example of how your array looks like, in code.

Comment: sample code that you tried?

Comment: Hi, this is the problem, I am not sure how to go about it. So far I can find the max from all by using  f("Q1")['1'].set(Max(f("vQ1").values())). But I need the top 3 max values

Comment: One option is to sort the list and get the 3 edge elements. But it's not efficient. A more efficient way is to find the max, then remove it from the list and repeat for 2 more times

Comment: Hi @PubuduDodangoda, this sounds ideal - however I wouldn't want to stop after 3 - in case I have there are more of the same. For example - if the top numbers are 5,4,4,4 - then I want to include the other 4 and then randomly select two from those three 4's once I find the top. I have a script for the random with I can implement after but I just need the function for the top numbers.

Comment: In that case, loop once through the array and create a map, where the key is the array element, and value is a list of codes that have the element. Then follow the steps I stated to find the top 3 values. Then based on the occurrences list you can get the output.

Comment: Hey, I am pretty new to this - do you have an example of how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, here are the pseudo steps to achieve this,

First create a map by traversing through the array once,

```
let array = [
    {code: 'c1', value: 4},
    {code: 'c2', value: 4},
    {code: 'c3', value: 3},
    {code: 'c4', value: 4},
    {code: 'c5', value: 5}
]

let codeMap = map = array.reduce((rMap, item)=>{
    if (rMap[item.value])
        rMap[item.value].push(item.code)
    else
        rMap[item.value] = [item.code]
    return rMap
}, {})

let valueArray = Object.keys(codeMap)

// Then repeat the following steps n(as required) number of times
// 1. Find the max of valueArray, 
// 2. Remove it from the valueArray
```

Then when you have the top 3 values, you can refer the `codeMap` to find the codes related to the top values.

For example, here the top values are 5, 4 and 3
From 5, you get `c5`, from 4 you get `c1`, `c2` and `c4`. Total number of codes exceeds 3, therefore you stop from there. Then out of `c1`, `c2` and `c3` you can randomly select 2 codes

Comment: Thanks! I shall try this.

Comment: @Mollyblob If this answers your question, appreciate if you can upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Of course, once I can get this to work I will. I appreciate how quickly you got back to me.

Comment: Ok, so I can't figure out how to make this work - however I have come up with this. So far this is punching in the max for every option - instead of just the row which it is found - are you able to help edit this current script? var codes=f("vC2").domainValues();
var max = Max(f("vC2").values());

for( var i=0;i<codes.length;i++)
{
if(f('vC2')[codes[i]] == max)
{ 
 f("vC2Max")[codes[i]].set(max);

 }
}